# any way to close an embed graph? -tkinter & matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i've tried everything i could ever imagine on my own, with my little knowledge of tkinter and matplotlib, i have no clue how would i close the embed graph i created, here's the code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)  
import tkinter 

fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
plotf = fig.add_subplot(111)
window = tkinter.Tk()

def grafFertilidadeMulher():
    idadeM = [18,22,27,32,37,42,47,67,87,99] 
    fertilidadeRelativaM = [0.84,1,0.96,0.9,0.8,0.48,0.1,0.08,0.05,0.01] 

    plotf.plot(idadeM, fertilidadeRelativaM, linewidth='4', color='pink', marker='o', markerfacecolor='purple', markersize='8') 
    plotf.set_xlabel('idade') 
    plotf.set_ylabel('fertilidade relativa') 
    plotf.set_title('Perda de fertilidade com a idade')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)   
    canvas.draw() 
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()  

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window) 
    toolbar.update() 

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() 

def grafFertilidadeHomem():
    idadeH = [19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,99]
    fertilidadeRelativaH = [0.92,1,1,1,0.95,0.81,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.4]

    plt.plot(idadeH, fertilidadeRelativaH, linewidth = '4', color = 'cyan', marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'blue', markersize = '8') 
    plt.ylim(0,1.2)
    plt.xlim(17,100)
    plt.xlabel('idade') 
    plt.ylabel('fertilidade relativa') 
    plt.title('Perda de fertilidade com a idade') 
    plt.show()

def grafFertilidadeAmbos():
    idadeM = [18,22,27,32,37,42,47,67,87,99] 
    fertilidadeRelativaM = [0.84,1,0.96,0.9,0.8,0.48,0.1,0.08,0.05,0.01]
    idadeH = [19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,99]
    fertilidadeRelativaH = [0.92,1,1,1,0.95,0.81,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.4] 
    
    plt.plot(idadeM, fertilidadeRelativaM, linewidth='4', color='pink', marker='o', markerfacecolor = 'purple', markersize='8') 
    plt.plot(idadeH, fertilidadeRelativaH, linewidth = '4', color = 'cyan', marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'blue', markersize = '8') 
    plt.ylim(0,1.2)
    plt.xlim(17,100)
    plt.xlabel('idade') 
    plt.ylabel('fertilidade relativa') 
    plt.title('Perda de fertilidade com a idade') 
    plt.show()

btnFertilidadeMulher = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Mulher', command = grafFertilidadeMulher)
btnFertilidadeAmbos = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Ambos', command = grafFertilidadeAmbos)
btnFertilidadeHomem = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Homem', command = grafFertilidadeHomem)
btnCloseFertilidade = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'fechar', command = plt.close(fig))

btnFertilidadeMulher.pack()
btnFertilidadeAmbos.pack()
btnFertilidadeHomem.pack()
btnCloseFertilidade.pack()

window.title('Menu')
window.geometry("500x500") 
window.mainloop()
```

don't mind the weird language, it's an app i would develop for biology.

if anyone could give me a little hand it'd be nice

edit: i only have one of the graphs embed, i started by using plt.show(), and only later thought i should embed

Comment: What do you mean with close it? You can destroy the widget the same you would any other tkinter object: with the `destroy()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't *really* want to close the graph, you want to clear it out for the next data set, right? In that case the answer is to use `fig.clear()`. Like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import tkinter

def grafFertilidadeMulher():
    fig.clear()
    plotf = fig.add_subplot(111)

    idadeM = [18,22,27,32,37,42,47,67,87,99]
    fertilidadeRelativaM = [0.84,1,0.96,0.9,0.8,0.48,0.1,0.08,0.05,0.01]

    plotf.plot(idadeM, fertilidadeRelativaM, linewidth='4', color='pink', marker='o', markerfacecolor='purple', markersize='8')
    plotf.set_xlabel('idade')
    plotf.set_ylabel('fertilidade relativa')
    plotf.set_title('Perda de fertilidade com a idade')
    canvas.draw()

def grafFertilidadeHomem():
    fig.clear()
    plotf = fig.add_subplot(111)

    idadeH = [19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,99]
    fertilidadeRelativaH = [0.92,1,1,1,0.95,0.81,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.4]

    plotf.plot(idadeH, fertilidadeRelativaH, linewidth = '4', color = 'cyan', marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'blue', markersize = '8')
    plotf.set_ylim(0,1.2)
    plotf.set_xlim(17,100)
    plotf.set_xlabel('idade')
    plotf.set_ylabel('fertilidade relativa')
    plotf.set_title('Perda de fertilidade com a idade')
    canvas.draw()

def grafFertilidadeAmbos():
    fig.clear()
    plotf = fig.add_subplot(111)

    idadeM = [18,22,27,32,37,42,47,67,87,99]
    fertilidadeRelativaM = [0.84,1,0.96,0.9,0.8,0.48,0.1,0.08,0.05,0.01]
    idadeH = [19,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,99]
    fertilidadeRelativaH = [0.92,1,1,1,0.95,0.81,0.6,0.4,0.4,0.4]

    plotf.plot(idadeM, fertilidadeRelativaM, linewidth='4', color='pink', marker='o', markerfacecolor = 'purple', markersize='8')
    plotf.plot(idadeH, fertilidadeRelativaH, linewidth = '4', color = 'cyan', marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'blue', markersize = '8')
    plotf.set_ylim(0,1.2)
    plotf.set_xlim(17,100)
    plotf.set_xlabel('idade')
    plotf.set_ylabel('fertilidade relativa')
    plotf.set_title('Perda de fertilidade com a idade')

    canvas.draw()

def grafClear():
    fig.clear()
    plotf = fig.add_subplot(111)
    canvas.draw()

fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
plotf = fig.add_subplot(111)
window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
toolbar.update()

btnFertilidadeMulher = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Mulher', command = grafFertilidadeMulher)
btnFertilidadeAmbos = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Ambos', command = grafFertilidadeAmbos)
btnFertilidadeHomem = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Homem', command = grafFertilidadeHomem)
btnCloseFertilidade = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'fechar', command = grafClear)

btnFertilidadeMulher.pack()
btnFertilidadeAmbos.pack()
btnFertilidadeHomem.pack()
btnCloseFertilidade.pack()

window.title('Menu')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: i did intend to clear it all, but i suppose it also works this way. looking to do this was going to be my next target, thank you for your help. if this works i dont see why i'd be wasting my time trying to do something without changing everything.
thank you again!